# Netbeans JavaFX 2.0 Application

Tags: javafx-2

I'm developing a JavaFX 2.0 application using NetBeans, and I'm trying to deploy my application into a jar file.

I also need some external jars to be added. The build is made using ant which comes with Netbeans. 
Finally the manifest file looks like this:

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0

Ant-Version: Apache Ant 1.8.2

Created-By: 1.6.0_25-b06 (Sun Microsystems Inc.)

Implementation-Vendor: iulia

Implementation-Title: NewVersionV3

Implementation-Version: 1.0

Main-Class: com/javafx/main/Main

JavaFX-Application-Class: myapp.view.NewVersionV3

JavaFX-Version: 2.0

Class-Path: lib/commons-codec-1.3.jar lib/commons-httpclient-3.1.jar l
 ib/commons-logging-1.1.1.jar lib/httpclient-4.0.jar lib/log4j-1.2.16.
 jar 

Even having the Class-Path atribute there, generating the jar produces nothing
I found a console that tells me the problem :

Exception in thread "JavaFX-Launcher" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/log4j/Logger
```

Apparently it does not find the jars. I checked out and there are at the right location in dist/lib and my jar is in dist folder.

Anyone has an idea about this?

Thanks a lot,

Iulia

Comment: Did you use the Logger of log4j in your JavaFX application?
When you use clean and build in NetBeans can you start the jar file? And does NetBeans copy the JAR with org/apache/log4j/Logger to dist/lib?

Comment: Hi, I used the Logger of log4j in my JavaFX application. The jar cannot be started at all, even if I use clean and build. And yes, Netbeans copies the JAR from org.apache.log4j.Logger in the dist/lib folder. I know it's a strange behaviour, theoretically it really should work. I'm thinking of creating a simple Java Application with some external jars needed and try to deploy in a jar, and then do the same thing with a JavaFX application. Let's see what happens. Maybe I can do some steps further.

Comment: I had a similar problem and found a working solution. Visit [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6750249/javafx-2-0-application-referencing-external-jars "JavaFx 2.0 application referencing external jars") page. Hope this helps.