# JavaFx 2.0 application referencing external jars

Tags: javafx-2

I'm developing a JavaFx 2.0 application using Netbeans 7. 
The main application references another class library project added by rightclicking the 'Libraries' folder and selecting 'Add Project...'. Executing the application from netbeans works fine.

When deploying it to a jar file by 'Clean and build' and trying to execute it via console with

```
java -jar TestApp.jar
```

I get

```
Exception in thread "JavaFX-Launcher" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: net/pmoule/SomeClass
...
```

The dist/lib folder of my application contains the referenced library. So IMHO everything should be fine. Looking at the Manifest.MF contained in my application jar I get this

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Ant-Version: Apache Ant 1.8.2
Created-By: 1.6.0_23-b05 (Sun Microsystems Inc.)
Implementation-Vendor: pmoule
Implementation-Title: TestApp
Implementation-Version: 1.0
Main-Class: com/javafx/main/Main
JavaFX-Application-Class: testapp.TestApp
JavaFX-Version: 2.0
```

Where is my class path? How do I get Netbeans to add the correct classpath?

I tried adding it manually to the Manifest.MF by editing the one contained in the jar

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Ant-Version: Apache Ant 1.8.2
Created-By: 1.6.0_23-b05 (Sun Microsystems Inc.)
Implementation-Vendor: pmoule
Implementation-Title: TestApp
Implementation-Version: 1.0
Class-Path: lib/MyLib.jar        //THIS IS NEW
Main-Class: com/javafx/main/Main
JavaFX-Application-Class: testapp.TestApp
JavaFX-Version: 2.0
```

No success and same error.

All samples delivered with the JavaFX 2.0 SDK work by doubleclicking in WindowsExplorer or from the console by entering e.g.

```
java -jar PathAnimation.jar
```

But not any of these examples makes a reference to an external jar.

Some research lead me to this question: [Netbeans JavaFX 2.0 Application](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6268215/852274)
But without any solution so far.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Update: To satisfy the requirements listed at [Oracle](http://download.oracle.com/javafx/2.0/system_requirements/jfxpub-system_requirements.htm) I changed the platform to JDK 6_26; I added this line to the fxjar-task in the project's jfx-impl.xml `<attribute name="Class-Path" value="${jar.classpath}"/>`. Now the classpath is contained in the manifest.mf. The error is still the same :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found a working solution by myself.

All the external libraries in the dist/lin folder had a size of 0kb. So the exception was correct, of course.

To get my application running I did the following in the project's jfx-impl.xml:

**Add the classpath to manifest.mf**

```
<fxjar destfile="${jfx.deployment.dir}/${jfx.deployment.jar}" applicationClass="${main.class}" >
             <fileset dir="${build.classes.dir}"/>
              <manifest>
               <attribute name="Implementation-Vendor" value="${application.vendor}"/>
               <attribute name="Implementation-Title" value="${application.title}"/>
<!-- NEW -->   <attribute name="Class-Path" value="${jar.classpath}"/> <!-- NEW -->
               <attribute name="Implementation-Version" value="1.0"/>
              </manifest>
    </fxjar>
```

**Create an output dir for web deployment**

```
<property name="jfx.deployment.web.dir" location="${jfx.deployment.dir}/web" />
<mkdir dir="${jfx.deployment.web.dir}" />
```

**Set output dir for fxdeploy task**

```
<fxdeploy width="${jfx.applet.width}" height="${jfx.applet.height}"
              outdir="${jfx.deployment.web.dir}" <!-- NEW DIR -->
              embedJNLP="true"
              outfile="${application.title}">
        <info title="${application.title}"
              vendor="${application.vendor}"/>
        <application name="${application.title}"
                     appclass="${main.class}"/>
        <resources type="eager">
           <fileset dir="${jfx.deployment.web.dir}"> <!-- NEW DIR -->
              <include name="${jfx.deployment.jar}"/>
              <include name="lib/*.jar"/>
              <exclude name="**/jfxrt.jar"/>
           </fileset>
        </resources>
</fxdeploy>
```

Now, I can deploy my desktop application and execute ist via doubleclick from windows explorer or by entering

```
java -jar TestApp.jar
```

There still exists some issue with the content of my newly created web-dir.

1. The TestApp.jar ist not copied zo dist/web
2. The referenced external jars are not copied to dist/web

This is fine for me and will be fixed some time later.

Hope this helps anyone else.

Answer (score 0):

In Netbeans, under project => properties => Build => Packaging, did you check "Copy Dependent Libraries" ?

Comment: Thanks for the hint, the option is checked. As I wrote, the project's dist/lib folder contains the library in question after executing a "Clean and Build".

Comment: Did you follow these directions for FXDeployment? http://download.oracle.com/javafx/2.0/deployment/jfxpub-deployment.pdf

Comment: Yes, I followed the directions in the deployment guide. I even updated the Netbeans Plugin for JavaFX and updated the project's build files. Deployment without any external jar works fine. The issue just occures when including some external jar.

Answer (score 0):

You need to tell the fx:jar task what your classpath dependencies are:

```
<fxjar destfile="${jfx.deployment.dir}/${jfx.deployment.jar}" applicationClass="${main.class}" >
      <fileset dir="${build.classes.dir}"/>
      <manifest>
        <attribute name="Implementation-Vendor" value="${application.vendor}"/>
        <attribute name="Implementation-Title" value="${application.title}"/>
        <attribute name="Implementation-Version" value="1.0"/>
      </manifest>

      <!-- Setup the classpath for the generated .jar here -->
      <fx:resources>
        <fx:fileset type="jar" dir="lib" includes="MyLib.jar"/>
      </fx:resources>
</fxjar>
```

You also need to use fx:resources tag in your fx:deploy task instead of just resources. That should resolve the last two problems left in your answer.