# Issue in Working with Images in Javafx 2.0

Tags: netbeans, javafx-2

I am new to NetBeans IDE and Javafx 2.0. I have a small issue in working with Images in Javafx 2.0,  I am developing a small app using Javafx and ExcelSheet and I use NetBeans IDE 7.1 Beta Version

I initiaize my image as shown below

```
Image okImage = new Image("src/resources/ok.png");
```

When I run my app from netbeans using Run(F6) cmd everything works fine. But when I try to run my app out of netbeans say from Command Prompt by using the cmd java -jar Myapp.jar  I cannot see the image being displayed in the window.

Note:

I cant use the below mentioned way to initialize my Image

**`Image infoImage = new Image(getClass().getResourceAsStream("/resources/info.png"));`**

Because I want to use this image inside a static method

So I initialize the image as

```
final static Image infoImage = new Image("src/resources/info.png");
```

But, the Image is not displayed.

I am totally lost Please guide me

Answer (score 3):

You can use next notation for static call:

```
Image infoImage = new Image(MyClassName.class.getResourceAsStream("/resources/info.png"));
```

Comment: Hi Sergey Grinev, thanks for your reply.  I do tried this approach before posting my question in this forum. It works fine but the problem is my 3rd party jar(commons-lang3-3.0.1 from Apache) is not being picked up at runtime.  I am trying to solve this issue.  Meanwhile, if you have any other solutions or fix for this issue  please let me know.  Thanks in advance

Comment: Hi. I don't really understand how lacking 3rd party jar is connected with Image not being loaded in fx code. Why do you need other solutions?

Comment: Hi, as you have mentioned 3rd party jar is no where connected with Image.  But, when I execute myapp in netbeans it works fine.  When I execute in cmd promt it throws me runtime error saying class not found.  I am trying to resolve it by using the solution mentioned in this site "http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6750249/javafx-2-0-application-referencing-external-jars".